# How do I solve fultter app not installed in my device?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting a prompt on my mobile device asking if I want to install the app on my device. I give yes, then nothing happens! for the first time and the app never installed before

I tried to use the cmd to connect my mobile device , I tried to restart my device and I've done the same steps in my device setting again

Comment: Without more details it is very hard to help you. Are you trying to install your app by using `adb` ? Or by "tapping" on the **apk** directly from the device's filesystem ?